# PostgreSQL: Insert a row in a table from multiple tables in AFTER INSERT TRIGGER

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have four tables

```
CREATE TABLE ExhibitionsCollection (
    EXC_ItemAlphaKey CHAR (4),
    EXC_ItemNumKey SMALLINT,
    EXC_ExhName  CHAR (15),
    PRIMARY KEY(EXC_ItemAlphaKey, EXC_ItemNumKey)
   );

 CREATE TABLE ExhibitionsLocation (
    EXL_ExhName CHAR (15),
    EXL_ExhLocation CHAR (20)
   );

CREATE TABLE Exhibitions (
    EX_ExhName CHAR (15),
    EX_ExhStartdate DATE,
    EX_ExhEnddate DATE,
    EX_ExhDescription TEXT
    );

 CREATE TABLE ItemsLocation (
     ITL_ItemAlphaKey CHAR (4),
     ITL_ItemNumKey SMALLINT,
     ITL_ItemLocation CHAR(15),
     ITL_Startdate DATE,
     ITL_Endate DATE
  );
```

I wanted to create an AFTER INSERT TRIGGER ON ExhibitionsCollection, something like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_ItemInsertedIntoExhibition
  AFTER INSERT  
  ON ExhibitionsCollection
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE somefuntion();

 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION somefuntion() RETURNS TRIGGER AS
 $BODY$
   BEGIN


    INSERT INTO ItemsLocation (ITL_ItemAlphaKey, ITL_ItemNumKey, ITL_ItemLocation, ITL_Startdate, ITL_Enddate)

    /*I need to insert the values of those attributes with each new insertion in to ExhibitionsCollection*/

   END;
 $BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: *What* do you want to insert into `itemslocation`?

Comment: I want to insert the values of the attributes: ITL_ItemAlphaKey, ITL_ItemNumKey, ITL_ItemLocation, ITL_Startdate, ITL_Enddate INTO ItemsLocation for the new inserted Item in ExhibitionsCollection Table. So, for example if (PNTG, 1001, 'Exhibition1') is inserted in ExhibitionsCollection Table. ItemsLocation Table should be automatically updated with the following (PNTG, 1001, "the location of item based on the exhibition location i.e. Exhibition1", "the starting date of exhibition where the item in", "the ending date of exhibition where the item in").

Answer (score 0):

This (untested) statement assumes that the `SELECT` statement returns exactly one row, i.e. that `exc_exhname` and `exc_exhname` are foreign keys linking to the respective tables.

```
INSERT INTO itemslocation
   (itl_itemalphakey, itl_itemnumkey, itl_itemlocation, itl_startdate, itl_enddate)
   (SELECT
       NEW.exc_itemalphakey,
       NEW.exc_itemnumkey,
       exl.exl_exhlocation,
       ex.itl_startdate,
       ex.itl_enddate
    FROM exhibitionslocation exl, exhibitions ex
    WHERE exl.exl_exhname = NEW.exc_exhname
       AND ex.ex_exhname = NEW.exc_exhname
   );
```

Comment: Thanks that works with little modification. Thanks again.

Comment: Consider upvoting and/or accepting the answer if it helps.